# Show About and Contact Us page when they're clicked in the top menu.

Tags: php, theme-development, menus, pages

I have a page.php file wich simply looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

On the other hand I have made two pages named About and Contact Us in **my WordPress admin panel** and I've added them to my site's top menu.

Now when I add some content to one of these two pages and open it by clicking its name from the top menu the content is not shown. How can I fix this issue?

I want to show all of my self-made pages (pages that are made using WordPress admin panel and are different from single.pho, index.php, category.php and search.php) using the page.php layout. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include a loop to retrieve the page content. Something like:

```
<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

     //BELOW HERE
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

      <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

     //ABOVE HERE

      </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

### More on Page Templates:

Possible [Tutorial Starting Point](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/)

And Page Templates from the WP [Codex on Page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/):

> page.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s ID is not found, WordPress looks for and uses the theme’s default page
>   template.

So if you haven't assigned anything in the admin, and no more specialized templates exist, your page.php file is being called.

Comment: @naser.Sadeghi no problem!